# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLBodyElement> has no method 'css'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to eventually loop through all of the nodes inside body (not implemented yet) and get the background and text color from every node. However, I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLBodyElement> has no method 'css'`.  It is occuring on `var bg = node.css("background-color");`

Here is my code

```
function grabColors() {
    var colorArray = new Array();
    var body = $("body");

    console.log(body);

    body.each(function(index, node){
        console.log(node);
        getColorsFromChild(node);
    });
    console.log(colorArray);
}

function getColorsFromChild(node) {
    var bg = node.css("background-color");
    var bg2 = node.css("background");
    var color = node.css("color");

    if ($.inArray(bg, colorArray) == -1) {
        colorArray.push(bg);
    }
    if ($.inArray(bg2, colorArray) == -1) {
        colorArray.push(bg2);
    }
    if ($.inArray(color, colorArray) == -1) {
        colorArray.push(color);
    }
}
grabColors();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are tring to call jQuery function css on a DOM object given by `each`. You have to convert the DOM object to a jQuery object to call CSS-related functions on it.

*Change*

```
var bg = node.css("background-color");
```

*To*

```
var bg = $(node).css("background-color");
```