# How to get access to php array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, symfony

I have an application based on symfony 2.3 
In a jquery part of my twig file I need to access a php array.
I'm not sure about how to achieve this.

What I tried :

In the controller :

```
public function indexAction() 
{
    ...
    $items = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Item')->findBy(array(), array('position' => 'ASC')); 
    //$itemsjs = json_encode($items);
    ...
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        ...,
        'items' => $items,
        'itemsjs' => $itemsjs,
        ...,
    ));
}
```

In the beginning of TWIG file I have :

```
<script>
var cal1 = $('#cal1');
var cal2 = $('#cal2');
...

function fillCalendar(mois, annee, cal)
{
    cal.css('display', 'none');
    var id = $(cal).attr('id');
...

function changeMonths(step)
{
    ...
    {% for item in items %}
        fillCalendar(newMonth-12*Math.floor((newMonth)/13), newYear+Math.floor((newMonth)/13), {{ 'cal' ~ item.id }});
    {% endfor %}
    ...
```

Any help would be nice ...

EDIT :
Some more informations on my application : This part is based on http://www.symfocal.com/
But I need to modify the way calendars are displayed.
I modified the code inspired by your answers
No need to transform php array in json format - its transmitted to twig and so the array should be available to twig.
I get 2 lines but only the first one works (days appear)
If I consider the generated HTML I get the impression that the {% for item in items %} loop does not work correctly :
{{ 'cal' ~ item.id }} becomes allways cal1 - but for the second line it should become cal2 (there are two items in the database with ids 1 and 2)

EDIT2 :
I modified the code :
I replaced :

```
{{ 'cal' ~ item.id }}
```

by :

```
'cal{{ item.id }}'
```

Tested with

```
alert ('cal{{ item.id }}');
```

in the loop => works
But in the function fillCalendar I will get an error I had not before :
Uncaught TypeError: Object cal1 has no method 'css'

So when I call in the loop :

```
fillCalendar(newMonth-12*Math.floor((newMonth)/13), newYear+Math.floor((newMonth)/13), 'cal{{ item.id }}' );
```

I get this error on this instruction :
cal.css('display', 'none');
But I have defined cal1 and cal2 as you can see so I do not understand !

EDIT3 :
OK I have resolved this problem too thanks to this post :
[Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLBodyElement> has no method 'css'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107860/uncaught-typeerror-object-htmlbodyelement-has-no-method-css)
But now no dates are filled up - the id's of  elements seem to be right :

```
...
<td class="cell_calendar"><a id="cal1_cell_5" href="#"></a></td>
...
```

( On original symfocal the id makes the fill :

```
<a id="cal1_cell_5" href="#" title="2013-11-01">1</a>
```

)

No JS error occurs!

EDIT4 :
I added another line in the source code above :

```
var id = $(cal).attr('id');
```

I changed it before it was var id = cal.attr('id'); but as you saw with the modifactions I did this doe not work anymore.
Only it seems to me that I can't get the id in this way (later on when I ude id its undefined)

How can I get this id make it work ?

EDIT5: The original problem is solved - For the last jquery problem I made a new post :
[Can't get attr id with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737936/cant-get-attr-id-with-jquery)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: look at the generated page source (e.g. `view source` in your browser). You'll see EXACTLY what twig spit out for that `{{ itemjs }}`, and that will tell you how to access what's in it.

Comment: @MarcB Not "exactly", the browser may modify if it is incorrect markup.

Comment: @DerFlatulator: it's inside a `<script>` block. browser shouldn't be modifying anything, unless the inserted stuff looks like html.

Comment: Thanks - now I can see that the array was empty
I modified my code and edited the post : but the loop seems not to work right

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not a client-side langage, Javascript is. You need to write the content of the array with twig, because in the js code you can't access the php array:

```
<script>
var items = {{ itemsjs }};
...
{% for i in items %}
    alert ('{{ i.name }}');
{% endfor %}

...
```

Comment: Ok but when I try this 

    {% for i in items %}
        alert (i);
    {% endfor %}
I get a message error that i is undefined  --  so I concluded that I need to access i in twig too.
I modified my code and edited the post : but the loop seems not to work right

Comment: oups, `alert('{{ i.name }}')`